# Skype Web SDK Sending Images via IM

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm developing an application that incorporates the Skype for Business Online Web SDK. Within my application, I've managed to get Instant Messaging working by starting new conversations and making use of the *chatService.sendMessage* method as such:

```
var sendMessage = function(text) {
     currentConversation.chatService.sendMessage(text);
};
```

However, it is my understanding that this method only accepts text and it is crucial in this application for users to be able to send images (either as files/attachments or embedded within the chat itself).

I currently see no way to send a message via the SDK that includes a file / attachment. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Chat service has supports both "text" and "html" as message format. See property [supportedMessageFormats](https://ucwa.skype.com/reference/WebSDK/interfaces/_s4b_sdk_d_.jcafe.chatservice.html).

You can try and use supported format as html to send image path in html. I'm facing issues with my Visual Studio hence could not create a sample. But documentation should help you.

**Update**

Looking at the comment it seems we may not be able to use image tag. Are you sending this message to Skype for Web App only? If yes, then you can send image url as text and then render the image in the chat window on the other side since you have full control over the chat history UI (unlike Skype for Business client)

Comment: This is a good point, thank you for your input.

I've tested out the ChatService using "Html" as a MessageFormat and hard-coded content as such:

`conversation.chatService.sendMessage('<div style="font-size:16px;">Test</div>','Html');`

Which worked as expected.

However, if I try to do the same with an image it does not work. This method would be sufficient for what I'm trying to achieve as I can convert the image to its base64encoded data and use that as the <img> source:

`conversation.chatService.sendMessage('<img src="<base64string>">','Html');`

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Good to know this could help. Request you mark it as answer or upvote if this was helpful. It could be that not all the ta I'm not sure if all the tags are allowed. If you compare this with Skype for Business client, the images are sent as an attachment. I will update my answer with an alternate approach.

Comment: Upvoted but since I have less than 15 reputation it will not be displayed publicly. Yes, your update is a good point if conversations were restricted to my application's Skype for Web App only but I do not want to enforce such a method (if it is even possible) as for users to be able to communicate over Skype via my application with Skype for Business Client users or Skype OWA users, or regular Skype client users. I've also posted to the Skype for Web GIT page hoping for any kind of clarification.

Comment: Though I doubt id there is a work around available as I don't see a API to send attachment, please do post if you find some solution

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't support image as a first class message type. But you could always Base64 encode your image file (if you want to transmit a file) and send the contents across to the remote party. Of course, in this case the remote party needs to understand that this message is a base64 encoded representation of an image.